# HTTUrlConnection Set Header doesnt work

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have encounter recently an interesting problem. 
I am trying to access sametime by using the integrated REST API. To do that i wanted to prepare an XAgent that is doing the lookup and data connection for me.

The first two steps to connect to the Sametimeserver work perfectly fine but i have a problem with the last step. Regardless what i do i cant set the header of the GET request. I tried it with other fields then one mentioned below but it looks like its not setting the header.

Anybody any idea why setting the header in SSJS doesnt work?

```
var url = new  java.net.URL("http://oursametimeserver/stwebapi/RTCServlet?"+sid);       
conn= url.openConnection();   
conn.setRequestProperty("Rtc4web-Nonce",pid);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
writer.write(@Implode(conn.getHeaderFields()));
```

Please see the results:

{null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request], Cache-Control=[no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"], Expires=[Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT], X-Powered-By=[Servlet/3.0], Content-Length=[170], Content-Language=[en-US], Content-Type=[application/json], Connection=[Close], Date=[Mon, 09 Mar 2015 19:18:54 GMT], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=0000zwXn8VhNWlZ78jN4yfMJQrU:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly]}

Please ignore the Error 400. The rest api returns it because i am not submitting the RTC4WEB-NONCE field in the header. I get the same result when i use POSTMAN in chrome. With that value everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your approach slightly:

1) Write a small Java class that wraps all the call to Java objects, so you can call that one with a simple JS call. It takes the "map a untyped js variable to a typed Java method" guesswork out of the picture

2) Don't use the HttpUrlConnection class. Either use the ApacheHttp Client which is both available and has methods to set the header - or use the social business toolkit that has ready functions to connect to Sametime